# need to set limit the data comes from child table

Tags: oracle

Genres is my parent table and contents in one of the child table, what is want is need to set the limit for the data comes from child table, how can i achieve this concept?

Comment: Please provide your table and sample data.  And explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.